# Extract text from Nifi attribute

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I'm listing out all the keys in S3 bucket. Below is the flow.

Here in the keys as part of the filename attribute(**FetchS3Object** attributes) I have the complete path of the keys, out of which I want extract the last but one text

e.g.

If below is the complete path of the key

**/buckname/root1/subobject/subsubobject/path1/path2/path3/text.csv**

in the file name attribute I have **root1/subobject/subsubobject/path1/path2/path3/text.csv**, out of which I want extract **path2** text.

Any suggestions to extract text from the attributes please.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the getDelimitedField expression language function:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield

mypath = ${filename:getDelimitedField(5, '/')}